# How to evoke Groovy file from Maven POM

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven

I'm using the GMaven plugin to evoke a Groovy script I have defined in my Maven project.

So I have something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Running Unicorn</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scriptPath>
                    <path>${project.basedir}/src/main/script</path>
                </scriptPath>
                <source>
                    import Helper
                    new Helper().doSomething()
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When it goes to execute the `source` section of this plugin I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute (Running Groovy
>   Execution) on project test-project: startup failed,
>   script1540154364455.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class Helper [ERROR] 
>   @ line 1, column 1. [ERROR] 1 error

The path to the script directory is correct, I verified that and the ability to execute Groovy by printing out the path to the Groovy script `scriptPath.path`.

I'm using the documentation located here but to no avail:

https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/scriptpath.html

What am I doing wrong here? Any help or pointers would be appreciated

Comment: First check the error message: `1: unable to resolve class Helper `...

Comment: Do you have `${project.basedir}/src/main/script/Helper.groovy` like the docs state?